# How to implement a read table function in F#? (like Vlookup)

Tags: f#, vlookup

[image]

I need a function.
When I enter 0~15 and Protection, it'll return 45%.
Just like Vlookup function in Excel.
Is there a function like this one in F#?

(At website try F#, Learn -> Financial Modeling -> Using the Yahoo Finance Type Provider
It recommended us to use Samples.Csv.dll. However, I failed to install it and don't want to install that package just for a function :(.. )

---

I followed the tutorial (http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html)
and tried to run the program on my computer. But I am in trouble now

[image]

It couldn't identify the type CsvProvider (So I can't use the function Stocks.Load.)

What's the problem..?

Comment: Are you asking for a function to do this from F# into Excel?

Comment: What is the source of the data? If you're getting the data from CSV, then have a look at http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html and http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvFile.html. These are basically a more advanced versions of the CSV tools available in Try F#.

Comment: I want to read data from csv file to F#.

Comment: Using the csv type provider as Tomas mentioned is the easiest way to do that from F#.

Comment: Thanks!! I am learning.

Answer (score 4):

This is how the code looks when using the [CSV type provider](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html) in F# Data. To get this to work, you'll need to add reference to `FSharp.Data.dll`. The best way to do this is to install the package from NuGet. In Visual Studio, it will add reference for you, and in command line you can say:

```
nuget install FSharp.Data
```

Alternatively, if you are in an F# script file, then you need to install the nuget package and then add `#r @"C:\path\to\FSharp.Data.dll"`. Then you can write the following:

```
open FSharp.Data
// Generate type based on a local copy with sample data
type Data = CsvProvider<"sample.csv">
// Load actual data from a file (this can be a different file with the same structure)
let loaded = Data.Load("runtime/file/name.csv")

// Find row for a specified age range & look at the properties
let row = loaded.Data |> Seq.find (fun r -> r.Age = "0~15")
row.Protection
row.Saving
row.Specified
```

Answer (score 2):

A very simple way to do this is with a `DataTable`:

```
open System.Data
open System.IO
open LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv

let vlookup =
  let table = new DataTable()
  do
    use streamReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\data.csv")
    use csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, hasHeaders=true)
    table.Load(csvReader)
    table.PrimaryKey <- [|table.Columns.["Age"]|]
  fun age (column: string) -> table.Rows.Find([|age|]).[column]

//Usage
vlookup "0~15" "Protection" |> printfn "%A"
```

There's no lack of CSV readers out there. I used [this especially fast one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) (also available on NuGet).